# mdi child form don't work via opengl app in .NET

Tags: c#, opengl, frameworks, mdi, tao

This is my first question.
I start to computer graphics programming with opengl via Tao Framework.

Everything going well but today I tried to work with MDI forms. My application crashed. It is a bit difficult to describe my problem. So I captured 5 images and I added my questions on them. I could not add this images because of my reputation. This is my homepage link. Thank you.

Please read all details

http://www.emrekiyak.com/tao.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are setting the MyParentForm property as the form itself, which creates a circular reference.

You could parametrize the child form Constructor to carry a reference to the parent, which will allow you to properly set it.

```
public ChildForm(Form parentForm)
{
    //Other code
    MdiParent = parentForm;
    Show();
}
```

No need to keep it as a property elsewhere.